# Play Store icons are no longer transparent

Tags: google-play-store, app-icons

The past few days I have noticed that the Play Store icons have a black background. I've even done a Factory Reset. I am facing the problem with every icon in the play store. Is there any way to get rid of it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a [known bug in the Play store app from v4.8.20](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/nexus/tw1FebzJQng). Try uninstalling the updates to the play store app. This could be a temporary fix until the bug if fixed in a future version of the app.